# Why am I getting a undefined symbol error for cuMemcpyDtoH_v2 in CUDA

Tags: python, cuda, linker-errors

I am getting undefined symbol error for cuMemcpyDtoH_v2 when trying to compile my code.  I guess my question is where is cuMemcpyDtoH_v2 defined?  I thought it would be defined in the cuda runtime enviornment but that appears to not be the case.  Here is my code:

```
#include </usr/local/cuda/include/cufft.h>
#include </usr/local/cuda/include/cuda.h>

void main()
{
   ...
   cuMemcpyDtoH_v2(v1, v2, ds);
   ...
}
```

To compile I am using the python disutils.core setup.py since I am linking python code to cuda code and creating a Python C extension.

```
python myFunc.py -build_ext --inplace -lcudart -lcufft -L"/usr/local/cuda/lib64/"
```

myFunc.py has a call to the disutils.core.setup() command which is used to compile python extensions.

I assume that cuMemcpyDtoH_v2 would be defined in the cuda runtime enviornment which I believe that I am linking to with the "-lcudart" command but perhaps that is not the case.

I am very new to C++ programming and Cuda so I could perhaps be making a very stupid mistake somewhere.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you have to link against `-lcuda`.  `-lcudart` links against the [CUDA runtime API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html).  `-lcuda` links against the [CUDA driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html).  Functions beginning with `cuda...` usually belong to the runtime API.  Functions beginning with `cu...` usually belong to the driver API.  Also note that you may have to specify an additional `-L/...` switch, because the `cuda` library is not usually in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`.

Comment: If you can't locate where `libcuda.so` is on your machine, it may be sufficient to link against the stub library using `-L"/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs"`  And normally order would be important here, meaning usually the `-L` switch would precede the `-l` switch, but I'm not familiar with the python distutils system.

Comment: @RobertCrovella:  linking to -L"/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs" did not seem to work.  Do you have any idea where the main libcuda.so could be?

Comment: It is installed by the GPU driver.  If you don't have a GPU driver installed on your system (for example if you are on a build machine) then there won't be an ordinarily installed `libcuda.so` on your machine (and that is what the stub version is for).  If you have a GPU driver installed, the driver will install it in a location that is OS-dependent.  Use a linux utility to locate it on your machine, such as `find`.

Comment: Also note that you don't link to just `-L"/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs"`.  That is just a file path telling the linker where to look for a library.  You need something like `-L"/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs" -lcuda`  When you try something new, you might want to update your question (click the edit link below it) to update with what you have tried: provide the full command line so we don't have to guess what you did exactly.

Comment: as an additional diagnostic, you might want to see if you actually have a directory on your machine that is `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs` and if it has a `libcuda.so` file in it.  It's good practice to mention which CUDA version you have installed, for questions like these.

Comment: @RobertCrovella:  It is working now.  There was a weird file permissions issue with libcuda.so that I fixed.  It is able to find and link to it now.  Thanks so much for the clarification on -lcuda and -lcudart.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Robert Crovella I was able to get this working.  According to Robert function calls that start with cu usually link to the driver API and functions that start with cuda usually link to the CUDA rumtime API.  So I needed to link to the cuda driver API using the following command:

```
python myfunc.py -build-ext --inplace -lcudart -lcudafft -L"/usr/local/cuda/lib64" -lcuda -L"/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/"
```

Note:  I am using CUDA version 9.1